# Quicksort Implementations Using a Random Pivot

Tags: quicksort

Are there any widely used Quicksort implementations which use a randomly selected pivot?

I ask, because [the `C` library `qsort` function](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/qsort.c) is implemented using "[Tukey’s ‘ninther’, the median of the medians of three samples, each of three elements](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8162&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" and performs significantly better than randomized quicksort.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it is true that the expected time of random pivot Quicksort is `O(nlogn)` .

But I think implementations with random pivot selection would be rare, if existing, since its not practical. Reasons:

- The cost of true randomness is high in execution time.
- Using pseudo randomness means that it is possible to construct an input which drives the sort to `O(n^2)`

Take a look at this Hacker News thread: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1442849

If this information is incorrect, please tell me so that I can update this answer.